# FFMPEG install php. Anyone know any good guides?

Tags: php, linux, ffmpeg

I would like to be able to convert videos to flv through the use of php and FFMPEG.

I was just wondering if anyone knew any good guides to setting up FFMPEG in a linux environment. I have found scripts showing how to use ffmpeg through `exec()` with php but I would like to know how to set everything up.

Also, I believe other software also needs to be installed in order for FFMPEG to work (ex. mp3 codecs?). If anyone could point me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it. I have been trying to search for ways to do this, but a lot of guides are outdated and some of the `wget` commands do not even work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for specific guides, would be useful to know which linux distribution you are using. As far as what *else* you need apart from ffmpeg, depends on what exactly you wish to be encoding. For example, if you wish to be able to encode xvid videos into flv, you'll need the [Xvid codec](http://www.xvid.org/).

I would recommend getting at least:

- FAAD2
- FAAC
- LAME
- yasm
- x264
- xvid

If you intend to encode mp4 videos with h264, you'd need qt-faststart as well, to move the meta data to allow immediate streaming.

(and personally prefer mencoder over ffmpeg)

Comment: Sorry, I am testing on Ubuntu and my remote server is CentOS. I want to be able to convert mpeg avi WMV and that's about it into FLV.

Comment: @Scarface avi, mp4 etc. are just container formats. They can use many different codecs. This ubuntu guide seems to have most of the necessary stuff: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=786095

Comment: When I need to move it to CentOS will the process of installing be much different? Also why do you like mencoder better?

Comment: I've used mp4's always, generally very high bitrate (2500kbps) etc. so the quality of the videos have been generally very high. Mencoder from my experience does a slightly better job, especially when it comes to audio (problems). I've never used flv, so I can't comment on whether mencoder is better or worse than ffmpeg for that. For centos, http://thenitai.com/2009/02/24/installing-ffmpeg-on-centosredhat-5x-successfully/ seems to have most of the stuff as well

Comment: Thanks a lot Niklas, I will go mess with this now and try to get something working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: http://wiki.collectiveaccess.org/index.php?title=Compiling_ffmpeg

I am a CollectiveAccess user, which uses `ffmpeg` for video processing.  Those instructions were pretty much spot on when installed a new CA system on a fresh CentOS.

`ffmepeg`, and its dependencies, work best when compiled from latest source since the `yum` repositories lag a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. What is CollectiveAccess?

Comment: CollectiveAccess is a collections management system.  It is primarily used by museums to catalog their stuff, including digitized assets.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-ffmpeg
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

That's should do the job (on ubuntu/debian at least)

Comment: Do I need any other codecs though? Check this out http://vexxhost.com/blog/2007/05/20/how-to-convertencode-files-to-flv-using-ffmpeg-php/ This guy says you need like 10 things. Some of those sites don't even work any more since it is from 2007 so that's why I ask.